# How can I improve this sentence about me professionally?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> where would you like to be professionally in ten years?

I wrote a passage in response to this question:

> Since my childhood, and **when I get familiar with computer** I would like to be a programmer. My father helps me to increase this appetite with buying a computer and provide tools that I needed for **learning programming and working  with computer**. I joined to **group working in programming field** that helped me the most to get many experiences. Therefore I'd like open my own computer company **for both programming and teaching**. This way, I can make enough money and share my experience with everybody who like to be a programmer.

Now I think there are many wrongs in my sentences for example I bold some words

I am not sure if I use right words and grammar. Also, I see several use at `with` in passage. Is it unconventional?

Comment: Not only the words in bold, your whole post is difficult to understand. E.g. "_Now I think there are many wrongs(**mistakes**)_".

Comment: Make sure to check your spelling and capitalization throughout.  Most of the errors lie in verb tenses; is there some specific question about tense use that you would like you ask?  I suspect that this will be closed as it is primarily a proof-reading request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to correct all of your sentences. You have started off with the right idea ( by bolding stuff) if you are having trouble with working your sentence try flipping it around instead of saying "since I was a kid I liked computers " say "I have liked computers since I was a kid". Hope this helps!

Comment: "kid" is too informal for this question in my opinion.